# Change wording of history (member since)

Tags: users

Is there a way to change the wording of "Member since" to something else?

Answer (score 2):

You could put this in your settings.php

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
   'Member since'      => 'Your new label',
);
```

Or you could change it in the form by preprocessing that form.  I think there are also language modules that allow you to change phrases/labels site-wide.

Answer (score 2):

The module String Overrides: http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides lets you replace virtually any string with another string.

Some of its features (from project page):

> - Easily replace anything that's passed through t()
> - Locale support, allowing you to override strings in any language
> - Ability to import/export *.po files, for easy migration from the Locale module
> - Note that this is not a replacement to Locale as having thousands of overrides can cause more pain then benefit. Use this only if you need a few easy text changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace any occurrence of that string, then you can use the following method:

- In Drupal 6, add the following code to the settings.php file.

  ```
  $conf['locale_custom_strings_en'] = array(
    'Member since' => 'The string you would use',
  );
  ```
- In Drupal 7, add the following code to the settings.php file.

  ```
  $conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
    'Member since' => 'The string you would use',
  );
  ```
- For Drupal 6, and 7, you can use the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module, which has the pro of not requiring to edit the settings.php file. It is quite simpler to change the strings from a administration page, than editing a file present in the webserver, and to which few people should have access.

In Drupal 7, it would be possible to alter only the string used in the user profile with [hook_user_view_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_view_alter/7), such as with the following code added to a module.

```
function mymodule_user_view_alter(&$build) {
  if (isset($build['summary']['member_for']['#title'])) {
    $build['summary']['member_for']['#title'] = 'The string you would use';
  }
}
```